# Is there a reply only signature in Outlook 2011 for Mac?

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2011

I have successfully setup my signature but do not see an option to either not include my signature in replies or include a shorter version of my new email signature.  Anyone know if this option exists?  If not is there a workaround?

Comment: You missed the question...it was - can you have a DIFFERENT signature for replies. As far as I can tell, the answer is no.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. It only makes it the default for new emails and not for replies or forwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally found a work-around for this issue. I found on the [Microsoft support site](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macoutlook/no-signature-on-reply/a433d97f-4517-4392-ae69-9002c3e43ddb?tab=AllReplies#tabs).

It basically entails setting up an additional account(for the same email address) without a signature. you then create a rule that moves all incoming mail to the account without a signature and then flip a few toggle switches so that you are not receiving mail twice.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this is no, cannot remember where I read it, but I did somewhere..and we are stuck with the signature functionality in all its limitedness in outlook 2011 for Mac.  :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want your signature in new emails but nor replies and forwards, follow [the instructions in this blog post](http://robandlauren.com/2011/10/13/creating-keyboard-shorcuts-in-outlook-for-mac/). Basically, you have to create an Outlook keyboard shortcut for your Mac. Think this is the easiest way to do it.

> - After set­ting up my sig­na­ture in Out­look, I went to Sys­tem Pref­er­ences > Key­board > Key­board Shortcuts.
> - In the list on the left, I went down to Appli­ca­tion Shortcuts.
> - I hit the plus sign to add a new shortcut.
> - In the appli­ca­tions drop­down, I found Outlook.
> - The next step was extremely impor­tant to get this to work. In the Menu Title box, you need to add the menu name exactly as it appears in
>     the app. This does not include the path to this menu item. For
>     exam­ple my menu item was to insert my sig­na­ture called Stan­dard
>     (Draft > Sig­na­tures > Stan­dard), so I put just the word “Stan­dard”
>     in this box.
> - Then assign the key­board com­mand, save, and viola! You now have a key­board com­mand to add a sig­na­ture when­ever you like in Outlook.

Comment: One step to add:  Create a new message, then go to the drop-down and select the shortcut with your mouse once to insert it --it won't work until you do this step.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely have you signature for replies and forwards. All you need to do is enable your signature as the default signature for your email address.

1. Go to your signature menu in outlook
2. On the bottom right hand corner you will see a button called "Default Signatures.."
3. There you can select your signature

Comment: That's not what the question is asking. He's saying he cannot have a *different* signature for replies and forwards.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answer helps: http://www.office.mvps.org/faq_topic/signatures.html#sig2

It basically says that everything after

```
--<space><return>
```

gets stripped away.
It didn't work for me though... :(

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is make your standard signature a default signature.

`Outlook > Preferences > Signatures > Default Signatures` and select your existing signature as the default for your email account. Works for me fine.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to create two signatures: one for new emails and one for reply/forward emails and then set my default signature to "None". Then when I am creating an email, I manually select the "Signatures" dropdown menu and select the signature that I want.

Answer (score 0):

I did one signature for regular outgoing and one for replies.  I set the default to outgoing signature and when I am replying to emails I manually select the other signature from the drop down menu.  It is not very hard and I think this is the simplest way.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific with your detail, consider adding some reference and proof supporting what you state, and confirming this answer is not already answered in one of the existing answers on the post if applicable.